# How can I change the color of buttons when they are pressed or print a new message below when the false answer was chosen in flutter quiz-app?

Tags: flutter

I need help with my flutter project.
I programmed a quiz app. The problem is, I don´t know how to programm it that a message appears on the display or the color of the pressed button changes when the user chooses the wrong answer. This is my code:

```
class JohannWolfgangvonGoetheState extends State<JohannWolfgangvonGoethe>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: ()async => false,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar( 
            title: Text("Quiz zum Autor "),
           backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
            body:  Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight ,
              child: Column(
                children:<Widget> [
                   Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0)),
                  
                 Container(
                   alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                   child:  Row(
                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[ 
                          Text("Question ${questionNumber + 1} of ${quiz.questions.length}",
                        style:  TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22.0
                        ),),

                       Text("Punkte: $finalScore",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22.0
                        ),)
                    ],
               ),
              ),
                new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),       

                new Text(quiz.questions[questionNumber],
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),),

               new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                new Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch ,
                  children: <Widget>[
                        
                      MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: 120.0,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      onPressed: (){
                        if(quiz.choices[questionNumber][0] == quiz.correctAnswers[questionNumber]){
                          debugPrint("Richtig");
                          finalScore++;
                          updateQuestion();
                        }else{
                          debugPrint("Falsch");
                          **finalScore--; 
                          
                          }
                          },
                           child: Text(quiz.choices[questionNumber][0],
                            style:  TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                             color: Colors.black                 
                             ),)
                             ),
                                                MaterialButton(
                                                minWidth: 120.0,
                                                color: Colors.blue,
                                                onPressed: (){
                          
                                                  if(quiz.choices[questionNumber][1] == quiz.correctAnswers[questionNumber]){
                                                    debugPrint("Richtig");
                                                    finalScore++;updateQuestion();
                                                  }else{
                                                    debugPrint("Falsch");
                                                    finalScore--;
                                                    
                                                  }
                                                  
                                                },
                                                child:  Text(quiz.choices[questionNumber][1],
                                                  style:  TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                                      color: Colors.black
                                                  ),),
                                              ),
                                            
                          
                                          new Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch ,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              //button 3
                                               MaterialButton(
                                                minWidth: 120.0,
                                                color: Colors.blue,
                                                onPressed: (){
                          
                                                  if(quiz.choices[questionNumber][2] == quiz.correctAnswers[questionNumber]){
                                                    debugPrint("Richtig");
                                                    finalScore++; updateQuestion();
                                                  }else{
                                                    debugPrint("Falsch"); 
                                                    finalScore--;
                                                  }
                                                 
                                                },
                                                child:  Text(quiz.choices[questionNumber][2],
                                                  style:  TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                                      color: Colors.black
                                                  ),),
                                              ),
                          
                                              //button 4
                                               MaterialButton(
                                                minWidth: 120.0,
                                                color: Colors.blue,
                                                onPressed: (){
                          
                                                  if(quiz.choices[questionNumber][3] == quiz.correctAnswers[questionNumber]){
                                                    debugPrint("Richtig");updateQuestion();
                                                    finalScore++;
                                                  }else{
                                                    debugPrint("Falsch");
                                                    finalScore--;
                                                  }
                                                  
                                                },
                                                child: Text(quiz.choices[questionNumber][3],
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 20.0,
                                                      color: Colors.black
                                                  ),),
                                              ),
                          
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0)),
                                          new Container(
                                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                            child:  new MaterialButton(
                                                minWidth: 240.0,
                                                height: 30.0,
                                                color: Colors.red,
                                                onPressed: resetQuiz,
                                                child: new Text("Verlassen",
                                                  style: new TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                                      color: Colors.white
                          
                                                      ),)  
                                      )
                                  ),
                                          ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                          
                                )
                              ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                            }
                              void updateQuestion(){
                              setState(() {
                                if(questionNumber == quiz.questions.length +1 ){
                                  Navigator.push(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Summary(punkte: finalScore,)));
                          
                                }else{
                                  questionNumber++;
                                }
                              });
                            }
                             void resetQuiz(){
                              setState(() {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                finalScore = 0;
                                questionNumber = 0;
                              });
                            }
                          
                           
}


class Summary extends StatelessWidget{
  final int punkte;
  Summary({Key key, @required this.punkte}) : super(key: key);

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
        return  WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: Scaffold(
    
            body:  Container(
              child:  Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
    
                   Text("richtige Fragen: $punkte",
                    style:  TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30.0
                    ),),
    
                   Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
    
                  
                   FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: (){
                      questionNumber = 0;
                      finalScore = 0;
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Text("Quiz neustarten",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.black
                      ),),),
                    
                 
                 FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: (){
                   print( questionNumber);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text("Quiz neustarten",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.black
                  ),),) 

            ],
          ),
        ),

 
      ),
    );
  }
  
}
```

Why doesn´t it work?  Can somebody tell me how to programm it that a text appears when the wrong answer was chosen or that the buttons change their colors?
(The debugger goes through the line, where I print the text, but nothing happens. )I also tried to use a button without any functions to print the error-message but this also was not successfull.
Thank you in advance

Comment: There is nothing in your code that should (or could) prevent `debugPrint` from working. The problem lies elsewhere. What editors do you use? What is your OP system? What version of Flutter do you have?

Comment: I use visual studio and have the flutter version 3.19.0.  I want to see a new text when I pressed the wrong questionchoices.